# How to enable a button if none of the inputs are present?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to enable a button in angularjs if one of the inputs is entered, otherwise leave it disabled. I was able to disable a button checking for the only one input. How to do if all inputs are checked for 1 button? i tried something like this...

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!in1.length>0 || !in2.length>0 || !in3.length>0">test all</button>
```

Please check my code here..[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slokesh/q8u1x0n1/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is off in `ng-disabled`. Also, arguably, this is more elegantly done with an `ng-form` (or `<form>`) and a `required` validator, and would work if you have a dynamic number of buttons:

```
<div ng-form="groupForm">
  <input ng-model="foo.a" required>
  <input ng-model="foo.b" required>
  <input ng-model="foo.c" required>

  <button type="button" 
          ng-disabled="groupForm.$error.required.length === 3">something</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `&&` instead of `||` :

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!in1.length>0 && !in2.length>0 && !in3.length>0">test all</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty - but this will work:

```
 <button type="button" ng-disabled="!((in1 && (!in2 && !in3)) || (in2 && (!in1 && !in3)) || (in3 && (!in1 && !in2)))">test all</button>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/iandayman/q8u1x0n1/2/